# Genetic algorithm fitness not improving fast enough

Tags: c++, genetic-algorithm

I have a program that attempts to guess a phrase via using a genetic algorithm. At first the max fitness of the population goes up rapidly, but later on the max fitness score of the population goes up extremely slowly. What can I do to improve this?

I've tried to introduce a mutation into the population members themselves whenever there has been the max fitness that has been stuck at a particular score for a while. This fixes the problem of the program being stuck, but not the problem of the fitness going up so slowly.

Full Code here:
https://github.com/bharddwaj/First-Genetic-Algorithm/tree/master/Genetic%20Algorithm

fitness score is just the number of characters shared with the actual sentence the program is trying to guess.

```cpp
Chromosome crossOver2(Chromosome parentOne,Chromosome parentTwo,int numChanges){
        //generates child by switching n random elements between the two SELECTED parents resulting in two children
        //then the function random returns one of the children
        //IMPORTANT NOTE: I am not using pass by reference so the parameters are merely copies
        std::unordered_map<int, char> genesHolder;
        for (int i = 0; i < numChanges; i++) {
            std::random_device rd;
            std::mt19937 generator(rd());
            std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution2(0, members[0].getChromosomeLength() - 1); // inclusive
            int rand_num_3 = distribution2(generator);
            char gene = parentOne.genes[rand_num_3];
            genesHolder[rand_num_3] = gene;
            parentOne.genes[rand_num_3] = parentTwo.genes[rand_num_3];
        }
        std::unordered_map<int, char>::iterator it;
        for (auto it: genesHolder) {
            int key = it.first; // first accesses the key while second accesses the value
            char value = it.second;
            parentTwo.genes[key] = value;
        }
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution3(0, 1);
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 generator(rd());
        int rand_num_4 = distribution3(generator);
        if (rand_num_4 == 0){
            parentOne.calcFitness();
            return parentOne;
        }
        parentTwo.calcFitness();
        return parentTwo;

    }

void mutation(int mutationPercent,Chromosome &child,int numChanges){
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 generator(rd());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, 100);
        int rand_var = distribution(generator);
        if (rand_var <= mutationPercent) {

            for (int i = 0; i < numChanges ; i++) {
                std::random_device rd;
                std::mt19937 generator(rd());
                std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution2(0, members[0].getChromosomeLength() - 1);
                int rand_var_2 = distribution2(generator);
                std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution3(0, characters.size() - 1);
                int rand_var_3 = distribution3(generator);
                child.genes[rand_var_2] = characters[rand_var_3];
            }

        }
    }

void generateChildren3(int numChildren,int mutationPercent, int numMutationChanges,int numCrossoverChanges){
        //inefficient wheel of fortune method
        //using weighted probabilities based on fitness to 'spin the wheel' for who reproduces
        //going to use normalization method sooner or later
        std::vector<Chromosome> wheel;
        int fitness;
        int maxFitness = getMaxFitness();
        for (int i = 0; i < members.size(); i++) {
            fitness = members[i].fitness;
            int limit = (((float)(fitness))/((float)(members[i].getChromosomeLength())))*100;

            for (int j = 0; j < limit; j++) {
                wheel.push_back(members[i]);
            }


        }

        for (int children = 0; children < numChildren; children++) {
            std::random_device rd;
            std::mt19937 generator(rd());
            std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, 100);
            int rand_var = distribution(generator);
            int rand_var2 = distribution(generator);
            Chromosome parentOne = (wheel[rand_var]);
            Chromosome parentTwo =  (wheel[rand_var2]);
            //Chromosome child = crossOver2(parentOne,parentTwo, numCrossoverChanges);
            Chromosome child = crossOver3(parentOne,parentTwo);
            mutation(mutationPercent, child, numMutationChanges);

            members.push_back(child);
        }
        calcAllFitness();
        wheel.clear();
    }
```

Comment: Genetic algorithms are intended to find **approximate solutions** rapidly. They aren't expected to find exact solutions. So the behavior you're seeing is pretty much the expected behavior of a genetic algorithm. To improve performance, you *could* be more careful in the crossover function, by producing children that are (almost always) better than the parents. But that undermines the whole concept of a genetic algorithm, since in that case you've basically implemented a [hill-climbing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing) within the crossover function.

Comment: Oh, I thought my genetic algorithm was faulty because I watched the youtuber TheCodingTrain create a genetic algorithm that guesses a phrase accurately and efficiently .

Comment: There are three things that distinguish a genetic algorithm: the fitness function, the crossover function, and the culling function. I just noticed that you're using "wheel of fortune" for culling. Another method is simply to take N members of the population with the highest fitness, and cull the rest. That, of course, will also bring your genetic algorithm closer to a simple hill-climbing algorithm.

Comment: Why would that approach be better? I thought that simply choosing the most fit members is bad because sometimes genes from the lesser fit members are required.

Comment: True. Keeping lesser fit members reduces the odds that you'll get stuck at a local maximum. But it also reduces the odds that you can randomly select a pair of parents whose offspring is the exact solution to the problem. At some point the lesser fit members drag the overall population fitness down as fast as the new offspring raise it (which is what you seem to be experiencing). At that point, progress can only be made by being more selective when culling.

Comment: BTW, if you want other responses besides mine, it might help to [post a complete set of code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That way, others can actually experiment with your code, and maybe someone will tell you exactly what's wrong with it.

Comment: Okay I'll definitely try your method of picking N highest fitness members for reproduction. Should I just edit this post and post the complete set of code?

Comment: It's up to you. If you play around with the code and get it to work, that's probably the best way to learn.

Comment: I posted a link to my github repo because I figured that would be much easier. I haven't yet implemented your technique but I figured maybe you might have a better understanding if u saw the full code anyway?